# Deploy react/spfx app to sharepoint using azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sharepoint

In Azure git repo, I have taken sample react app code as shown below,
[image]

then I have to host this in app service using Azure DevOps so I created CI & CD pipeline as shown in below images, CI pipeline

[image]

CD pipeline
[image]

It's working fine now in the same way our development team give some react/spx app code in git repo now I want to host/deploy those into SharePoint. for this I need to set up CI/CD pipeline. As I am new to DevOps I am not sure about this setup. Please help me out.

When development team pushes code into git repo the pipeline automatically trigger and that should be hosted/deployed into sharepoint. The development team building code is related to custom screens for SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy your app to SharePoint, you can refer to this SharePoint's official doc [Implement Continuous Integration and Continuous deployment using Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/implement-ci-cd-with-azure-devops). This article explains the steps involved in setting up your Azure DevOps environment with Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment to automate your SharePoint Framework builds, unit tests, and deployment.

You can also refer to this blog [Deploying SPFx apps with Azure DevOps pipelines](https://www.blimped.nl/deploying-spfx-apps-with-azure-devops-pipelines/), which demonstrates how to create build & release pipelines in Azure DevOps to build and deploy an SharePoint Framework application.

To trigger your build pipeline when the team push code into the repo, go to your pipeline, click **Triggers** -> check **Enable continuous integration**.
[image]

To trigger the release pipeline when the build is complete, go to edit your release pipeline, click **Continuous deployment trigger** and enable it.
[image]

Learn more about trigger in the DevOps pipeline, see [Specify events that trigger pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops).

Comment: thanks for your response but i know how to enable trigger for automation and i also seen the documents you are refering but as you can see in my images in that way i want clear images & ci ,cd pipeline set for sharepoint. Can you please provide those.

Comment: I am bit confused in setup CI,CD for my requirement . So please provide those images & details please.

Comment: In the official document and blog I shared, there are very detailed steps including the tasks used and the corresponding parameters. Could you please elaborate on where you are confused?

Comment: Thank you . yes i will go through those documents again & get back to you. Meanwhile can you please let me know what credentials/information do i need to get from sharepoint team to perform those CI /CD set up as per your docuements.

Comment: If you are referring the official doc, you will need a username and a password to connect to SharePoint at step "Connecting to SharePoint Online". If you are referring to the blog, you will use an [Entra ID Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory) Registration and authenticate using the client credentials grant flow with a certificate. You can directly use the PowerShell scripts in the blog.